# Using OpenCV to find radius of a dome from a picture

Tags: python, opencv, math, image-processing, rotational-matrices

I have a camera positioned a known distance away from a dome, facing it at a known angle.

[image]
[image]

as seen from the picture, the dome has a strip on it so that I can use image processing to fit an ellipse to it and find the radius. If the camera was positioned at a 90 degree angle from the dome, the full radius could be seen (in this case 140mm.)
[image]

While if it was at 0 degrees, no curvature can be seen.
[image]

My question is, how does this vary with angle? I believe the answer lies in OpenCVs rotation matrices, but how can I use it for this purpose? If I have the following image from a known angle, how would I rotate it about an axis to find the radius as if viewed from a 90 degree angle?

[image]

Comment: Unrelated and sorry I can't answer your question, but could you say what software you made the diagrams with please? Blender?

Comment: Autodesk Inventor